Recovering a damaged WAV file
I hope that some one can save my life here!!!
I have a corrupted/damaged wav file, and can't repair it. Here is things I have already tried:

Using VLC Convert/Save facility, no success
Tried to import it as Raw data in Audacity, no success

In audacity the imported raw is just a blank track. Interestingly, I can't send the file per Mail (to myself!), possibly because it is damaged!
This is the output of soxi on the file:
soxi WARN wav: wave header missing extended part of fmt chunk

Input File     : 'Take4_Audio 1-1.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 25-bit
Duration       : 00:02:00.75 = 5795824 samples ~ 9055.98 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 23.2M
Bit Rate       : 1.54M
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Floating Point PCM

Also when I try to write the file to a new file with sox --ignore-length Take4_Audio\ 1-1.wav ~/Desktop/fix.wav, this happens:
sox WARN wav: wave header missing extended part of fmt chunk
sox FAIL sox: `Take4_Audio 1-1.wav' lsx_readbuf: Input/output error

Can any one help?

You may try https://github.com/agfline/wavfix, depending on the issue it might work. Do you know at which sample rate and bit depth the file has been recorded ?

Is the duration reported by soxi correct? You can work out the SR and bit-depth by using that and the actual file size.

@n00dles The duration is correct. But the file is empty!

What do you mean the file is empty? The samples are zeroed? If so, there's nothing you can do. You should post a link to the file, to be sure.
